# what is the difference between custom pop up window and view?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Hi I am implementing the pop up screen .Actually I found one code from one site .But i don't know how to know it is pop up screen or view.If we don't use custom pop up we do like that **modal : true**.But when we prepare custom pop up how to know it is pop up or screen?

**View**

```
/FirstView Component Constructor
function SecondView2(data) {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var dataArray =new Array();
    dataArray[0]="naveee";
    var wn = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor:'red'
    });
    var self = Ti.UI.createView({
        layout:"vertical",
        height:300,
        top:40
    });




    // Simplest list data items that can be displayed in a list view
var data = [
    { properties: { title: 'Row 1'} },
    { properties: { title: 'Row 2'} },
    { properties: { title: 'Row 3'} }
];

// Add the list data items to a section
var listSection = Titanium.UI.createListSection({items: data});

// Add the list section to a list view
var listView = Titanium.UI.createListView({sections: [listSection]});


var tableData = [ {title: 'Apples'}, {title: 'Bananas'}, {title: 'Carrots'}, {title: 'Potatoes'} ];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
  data: tableData
});


listView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e){

    //alert("ppp"+e.i);
    //add();
    var item = listSection.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);


    var modal = require('ui/common/Third').modalWin;
var popupWin = new modal();
popupWin.open();
  // alert(item.properties.title);
   // alert(e.itemIndex);



});

self.add(listView);




    wn.add(self);

    return wn;
}


**pop up window**

exports.modalWin = function(){

//Popup win
var popupWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({

backgroundColor : 'black',
opacity            : 0.5,
fullscreen        : true,
id                : 'popupWin'
});

//View that used to show the msg
var popupView = Ti.UI.createView({
width    : 200,
height    : 100,
backgroundColor : 'white',
borderRadius : 5,
borderColor : 'red',
borderWidth : 3
});

//A message label is added to the view
popupView.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({ width : 150, height : 'auto', top : 10 ,
text : 'This is Modal Window', backgroundColor : 'green',
font  :  { fontSize : 14, fontWeight : 'bold'}}));
popupWin.add(popupView);

/*Event to close the popup window*/
popupWin.addEventListener('click', function(e){
if(e.source.id != null){
popupWin.close();
}
});
return popupWin;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of usability there is not much difference. But as far as coding is concerned the popup effect of a window is done by the modal:true keyword. While in a view you have to give a lot of effort in design. You cannot distinguish it easily from the client side ie as a mobile user.

Comment: where  modal:true keyword  used in custom op up screen

Comment: Is that a question or reply ?

Comment: question ..Actually when I used custom pop up I never used modal true